Specifc Slider Style
I am currently trying to style an html slider so that it looks something similar to this:

However, my styling isn't working out and the slider thumb gets too close to the edge of the bar (ignoring the colors, not the concern right now):

I have done some research on how to do this, and Most of the styling here comes from that, but I still cannot get it to work properly, and haven't been able to find a solution that works.

EDIT: Code Snippet Added


/* STUDY DAY SLIDER */
.days {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 25%;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    outline: none;
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
  }

  .days::-webkit-scrollbar-track {

  }
  
  .days::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .days::-webkit-slider-thumb::before {
    content: var(--thumbContent);
    color: white;
  }
  
  .days::-moz-range-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="./example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" class="topic-row-style days" id="topic-row-style">
    </body>
</html>




What is testDateValue?

Can you update this to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem?

@mykaf That section of code just calculates the limit of the range based on two dates, it is not necessary as part of this issue, but as mentioned in the comment in the code, was included to give some context if needed (simply showing a single line of js didn't feel very helpful)

@David Just added

@kaitlynmm569: "the slider thumb gets too close to the edge of the bar" - Wouldn't .days simply need a left and right padding value then?

Don't include any JS if JS isn't the issue. We only need the minimal relevant code.

@mykaf There was a js issue mentioned. I am trying to get the slider to display the value on top of the thumb, and i am using that JS to set the value, which is not working.

@kaitlynmm569: That sounds like a separate issue from the styling issue being demonstrated above, and may be worth a separate Stack Overflow question demonstrating that attempt and indicating the problem encountered.

@David Got it, thank you. Sorry about the confusion

Try this:
I think this is what you are looking to do.


.days {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 25%;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 3px 8px; /* new line */
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
  }

  .days::-webkit-scrollbar-track {

  }
  
  .days::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .days::-webkit-slider-thumb::before {
    content: var(--thumbContent);
    color: white;
  }
  
  .days::-moz-range-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="./example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" class="topic-row-style days" id="topic-row-style">
    </body>
</html>




Looks like I was trying to add the padding to the wrong thing, thank you!
